# Image resizing with fixed width but dynamic height

Tags: image, math

Hi guys I'm cracking my head on this.

I have a couple of pics, all with different ration (`1288x1977`, `1044x1789` e.g).

What I'm trying to do now is to resize the original up to 2 smaller imagines with fixed widths(640 & 1024), but dynamical(percent based i guess) heights, so an original with `1047x1501` would devide into: `1024x1468` and  `640x917`, those are the expected results but i can't wrapp my head arround the maths to do this. I hope you can help.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "aspect ratio". You want the ratio of width/height to be the same in the resized image as in the original. So you know the original width and height and the new width; solving a simple proportion should get you the new height...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to derive the height from a desired width while maintaining the aspect ratio?

That's math, actually, rather than programming:

```
Aspect = orig_width / orig_height

Aspect = new_width / new_height
```

so

```
orig_width / orig_height = new_width / new_height
```

so

```
new_height * (orig_width / orig_height) = new_width
```

so

```
new_height = new_width / (orig_width / orig_height)
```

Comment: well the width is always fixed, so the results have always to be like 640x? and 1024x?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't change the basic formula.